# Why ExecuteResult method without body in JsonResult class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, abstract-class, actionresult, jsonresult

In MVC, `ActionResult` is abstract class having `ExecuteResult` abstract method.
Of-course, `ExecuteResult` will be implemented where `ActionResult` will inherited.

`JsonResult` is inheriting `ActionResult` class. So as per the basic rule I expect the implementation of `ExecuteResult` method in `JsonResult` class.

See below images.

ActionResult class
[image]

JsonResult class
[image]

But here no body or concrete implementation of `ExecuteResult` method in `JsonResult` class. However the method is overrides but without the body or implementation.

So where is the actual implementation of this abstract method?

Answer (score 2):

That is how your Visual Studio is behaving. We need parituclar settings turned on to see the built-in libraries source code in VS which i can't recall, but you can see the [source code for it here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8723842/) which is :

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
            String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed);
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)) {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null) {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null) {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, you cant see any of the implementation details of the built in classes by default. For that install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SchabseSLaks.Ref12) plugin in your VS

Comment: I have just install Ref12 extension in VS2015 and restart visual studio. But not able to see any implementation details of the build in classes. Do I have to to anything else?

Comment: well https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs is the link to the source code of the JsonResult class but of course you cant use the f12 shortcut with it